# How to change primary monitor permanently (with ATI driver)?

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors

How can I change the primary monitor in Ubuntu 11.04 permanently in dual-monitor mode using the ATI-driver. I succeeded to change it with this command:

```
xrandr --output DFP2 --primary
```

But I have to perform this command after every login.